# Infinite chain of homomorphisms between triangle-free graphs with bounded max average degree?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

We use $G\to H$ to denote "there exists a homomorphism from graph $G$ to $H$", i.e. exists a map $h:V(G)\to V(H)$ s.t. $(x,y)\in E(G)\implies (h(x),h(y))\in H$. Let mad$(G)$ denote the max average degree of $G$, i.e. $\textrm{mad}(G):=\max_{H\subseteq G\textrm{ a subgraph}}\frac{2|E(H)|}{|V(H)|}$.

Observe that the sequence of cliques $(K_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an infinite ascending chain of homomorphisms in that $K_i\to K_{i+1}$ but $K_{i+1}\not\to K_i$. I wonder if an infinite ascending chain still exists when we add degree and configuration constraints. In particular,

[1] Is it true that for any $\alpha \geq 2$, there still exists an infinite **ascending** chain of *finite, connected graphs* $(G_i\stackrel{\not\leftarrow}{\to}G_{i+1})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ satisfying
$$(1.1)\quad \forall i, \textrm{mad}(G_i)\leq \alpha$$
and
$$(1.2)\quad \textrm{each }G_i\textrm{ is triangle-free}?$$

Note that trees are all homomorphically equivalent to a single edge, so if $\alpha < 2$ (meaning $G_i$'s do not contain cycles as subgraphs) there does not exist such an infinite ascending chain.

Also note that an infinite **descending** chain $(G_i\stackrel{\not\to}{\leftarrow}G_{i+1})_i$ satisfying (1.1)+(1.2) exists for all $\alpha\geq 2$: for example let $G_i:=C_{2i+5}$ the odd cycles.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **yes** for any $\alpha \geq 2$ and **no** for $\alpha=2$.

Actually you can find any countable partial order as an induced suborder in the planar cubic triangle-free graphs ordered by homomorphism. This is a result of [Jan Hubička and Jaroslav Nešetřil](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669804000502).

The result is proved as follows. First, they proved that any countable partial order exists as an induced suborder in the directed paths ordered by homomorphisms. Then, they used a substitution method to change the directed graphs into undirected graphs:

[image: substitution rule]

(taken from p.16 from [this slide](http://www.ucw.cz/%7Ehubicka/slides/bordeaux.pdf))

The substitution perserves the order by homomorphisms, namely, there exists a homomorphism between directed paths $G \rightarrow H$ iff there exists a homomorphism between the respective replaced graphs.

The reason that the substitution method works is because the replaced graph (a subdivided $K_4$) is "rigid", i.e. the only homomorphism to itself is the identity.

By lemma 2.3 of the paper [Chromatically optimal rigid graphs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895689900397), the graph below is rigid ($l$ can be arbitrary large):

[image: rigid subdivision of K4]

So by using this graph in the substitution method, we can generate a set of graphs with $\text{mad}$ bounded by any $\alpha>2$ and contains any countable partial order as an induced order.

For $\alpha=2$, notice that all the connected graphs are either trees or graphs with a single cycle. By taking the [cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_(graph_theory)), they have cores either a cycle, an edge or a single vertex. It turns out that there is no infinite ascending chain.

Comment: I'll check the techniques soon, but I get the idea and outline now. Thank you so much!